# Using ternary operator to select among two sets of integer values

Tags: c#, sql, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two sets of integer values like below

```
int[] x = {12,4,7,23,1,21,3,34,15,11,35,39,19,31}
int[] y = {28,9,17,8,2,20}
```

I have to choose a set based on below condition

```
var useID = (PermitType == 1)? x:y;
```

I will be using this in my LINQ query as below

```
 var query = from NC in dbContext.NC
                        where  NC.useID in useID
                        select NC;
                 var output = query.ToList();
```

Is this right approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `useID` after the conditional (ternary) operator will have an array of `int` values. That you can use in your LINQ query like:

```
 var query = from NC in dbContext.NC
             where  useID.Contains(NC.useID)
             select NC;
```

Or with a method syntax:

```
var query = dbContext.NC.Where(row => useID.Contains(row.useID);
```

As far as this `where  NC.useID in useID` syntax is concerned you have to use `Contains` for something like (`SELECT * FROM YourTable where col1 IN (1,2,3);`)